# Why does tika provide 2 identical content-types for a single file

Tags: java, content-type, apache-tika

Rather naively I apply

```
InputStream in = ...
Metadata tikaMeta = new Metadata();
Tika tika = new Tika();
tika.setMaxStringLength(-1);
body = tika.parseToString(in, tikaMeta);
```

to convert a file. The `body` stays empty, which is ok, because it is a binary executable. But a debug log of the content-type meta reveals:

```
Content-Type->[application/x-executable, application/x-executable]
```

Any ideas why Tika provides two content types?